# ggplot & colors: is it possible to create a fixed gradient of colors across different plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors, gradient

When I specify a scale of colors with ggplot, it plots the variable assigning a shade of color according with the gradient it creates using the values of the variable.

For example:

```
  ggplot(aes(fill = `Real Wage`)) +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c( "white","yellow", "orange", "red")
```

Is it possible to create a fixed gradients of colors for the values of an interval 0- 1000 and then ask to ggplot to use that gradients to paint rather than create its own gradients using the values of the variable?

The reason is that i need the same gradient of color for different variables and I don't want that it creates a new gradient for each one of them according with their values

Comment: Yes, you can use the `limits` argument of `scale_fill_gradientn` just like you might set axis limits for the x or y axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `limits` argument in `scale_fill_gradientn()`:

```
library(ggplot2)

grad <- c("white","yellow", "orange", "red")
grad_lims <- c(12, 31)

ggplot(mpg, aes(factor(cyl), drv, fill = cty)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = grad, limits = grad_lims) +
  theme_void() +
  ggtitle("City Mileage")

ggplot(mpg, aes(factor(cyl), drv, fill = hwy)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = grad, limits = grad_lims) +
  theme_void() +
  ggtitle("Highway Mileage")
```

[image]

[image]